# Set default values from another xml for empty nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

**Given:**

File with data:

```
<doc>
     <a>some text(<p>text here</p>) or blank</a>
     <b>same</b>
</doc>
```

File with default values:

```
<doc>
     <a><p>Dummy text</p></a>
     <b><p>Dummy text</p></b>
</doc>
```

**I got** this xslt to get the defaults from the second file:

$file = file path with default values

```
<a>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//a!= ''">
            <xsl:copy-of select="//a/p" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:copy-of select="document($file)//a/p" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</a>
```

With this it works well and all, the only problem is that I would like to make an **iteration** through the **xml nodes** and make an automated process to improve scalability and save time entering every time the same condition fro each node. But I can't find a way to use the **document() function** with variables for the **xpath**, **document($file)$nodexpath** doesn't work.

I might be missing something, just started recently with xslt, if any of you could give me some advice I would appreciate It greatly.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
The actual data resembles more an xml like this, it can have more deepth levels.

```
   <doc>
       <object>
          <group1> 
              <a>(<p>text here</p> or blank)</a>
              <b>(<p>text here</p> or blank)</b>
              <c>
                 <c1>(<p>text here</p> or blank)</c1>
                 <c2>(<p>text here</p> or blank)</c2>
              </c>
          </group1>
          <group2>
              <d>(<p>text here</p> or blank)</d>
          </group2>
       </object>
    </doc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally resolved it, I'm posting my solution here, thanks Daniel for your answer, it helped me a lot:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <doc xml:lang="es">
            <object>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </object>
        </doc>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current() != ''">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="self::p">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="file" select="document('template.xml')"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select ="$file//*[name()=name(current())]/p"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try matching any element that doesn't contain a child element or text and pull the default based off of the name.

There doesn't seem to be a reason to try to match xpaths based on your example. If your actual data is more complicated, update your question and I can update my answer.

Example:

**XML Input** (Added empty `a` and `b` to get default values.)

```
<doc>
    <a>some text(<p>text here</p>) or blank</a>
    <a/>
    <b>same</b>
    <b/>
</doc>
```

**so_defaults.xml**

```
<doc>
    <a><p>Dummy text for "a".</p></a>
    <b><p>Dummy text for "b".</p></b>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="defaults" select="document('so_defaults.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(text())]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$defaults/*/*[name()=name(current())]/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <a>some text(<p>text here</p>) or blank</a>
   <a>
      <p>Dummy text for "a".</p>
   </a>
   <b>same</b>
   <b>
      <p>Dummy text for "b".</p>
   </b>
</doc>
```

Comment: Well i actually have a more complex structure with more deepth levels, I will edit my queestion to put a better example