# Using xslt to generate an xml given an xml with data and an xml template with default values

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello i'm having troubles with xslt and I would appreaciate greatly your help,

I've got an xml with some data I want to parse using xslt and a template file with the data structure and default values for the empty nodes.

I want to generate an xml using the template structure using the default values or the data given by the input xml  depending on whether it has text or is empty.

I've tried iterating the nodes but I'm new to xsl and i don't get anything clear, thanks in advance.

**Data:**

```
<doc>
   <object>
      <group1> 
          <a>(<p>text here</p> or blank)</a>
          <b>(<p>text here</p> or blank)</b>
          <c>
             <c1>(<p>text here</p> or blank)</c1>
             <c2>(<p>text here</p> or blank)</c2>
          </c>
      </group1>
      <group2>
          <d>(<p>text here</p> or blank)</d>
      </group2>
   </object>
</doc>
```

**Template:**

```
<doc>
   <object>
      <group1> 
          <a><p>default text</p></a>
          <b><p>default text</p></b>
          <c>
             <c1><p>default text</p></c1>
             <c2><p>default text</p></c2>
          </c>
      </group1>
      <group2>
          <d><p>default text</p></d>
      </group2>
   </object>
</doc>
```

Right now I'm generating the output xml evaluating every node like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="file" select="document('template.xml')"/>    
<a>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//a != ''">
              <xsl:copy-of select="//a/p" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:copy-of select="$file//a/p" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
</a>
<b> ... </b> ...
```

The code to iterate that i'm trying which results in all blank:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(text())]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$file//*[name()=name(current())]/p"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set default values from another xml for empty nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743037/set-default-values-from-another-xml-for-empty-nodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally resolved it, I'm posting my solution here:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <doc xml:lang="es">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </doc>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current() != ''">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="self::p">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="file" select="document('template.xml')"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select ="$file//*[name()=name(current())]/p"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This code will do the trick as long as you don't need to distinguish between 'group1/a' and 'group2/a', i.e. as long as the name of the context node is adequate to identify the replacement text. I have a couple of solutions in mind that might work if you need to identify replacement text by longer XPaths. BTW, your code outputs an extra 'object' element.

Comment: True, I just made a renaming from my actual code in which the input xml is slightly diferent (doesn't have the doc node), anyway i edited it to remove the first object. In my case the nodes in my template are all unique so it doesn't matter but if you can figure out a way to actually get the complete xpath from the node It would be great to know.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to parse your xml file ? Saxon ?

You can test replacing

```
<xsl:copy-of select="..." />
```

By

```
<xsl:value-of select="..." />
```

But I don't think the problem is here. You have to run through all your nodes recursively and in a Blank case, you should parse the 'Template.xml' value at this node.

Test something like :

```
<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(Current()='')">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$file/name(Current())" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
```

It doesn't work I think, because I can't test now and I forgot the syntax but it should be something like this.

Comment: I actually don't have any way to trace xslt errors, but the result is just blank. I've edited the post with the code i'm trying

Comment: I think your first template never select the second in your general apply-template. I edited my answer